# What is the equivalent of entityEntry.Metadata.DefiningNavigationName() in EF Core 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0, ef-core-6.0

I am using EF Core 5 and I have the following in my DBContext SaveChanges():

```
            if (entityEntry.Metadata.Name == "ArticleBankAggregate.ArticleTag" && entityEntry.Metadata.DefiningNavigationName != "Tags")
            {
                entityEntry.Property("UpdatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;

                if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)

                {
                    entityEntry.Property("CreatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
```

To update a shadow property.

I am trying to upgrade to EF Core 6 and I get the following:

CS0618: 'IReadOnlyEntityType.DefiningNavigationName' is obsolete: 'Entity types with defining navigations have been replaced by shared-type entity types'

I cant find any examples or understand how to change this to use shared-type entities.

Comment: Both `DefiningNavigationName` and `DefiningEntityType` now return `null`. I'm not quite sure what is their purpose in pre EFC 6.0 (looks like something related to owned entity types), can you post a sample model and what are you trying to check with that code?

Comment: @IvanStoev ArticleTag is just an entity class that is owned by two other entities in the same project.  On one of the classes that owns ArticleTag I want to have shadow properties of UpdatedDate and CreatedDate and the other class that owns ArticleTag I dont want the shadow properties.  The second owning class's property for ArticleTag is name Tags. Does this help?

Comment: Ok, so you are really talking about "owned entity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared entity types are entity types which use common CLR type (class), and are identified by the entity type name (since the type is not enough).

Owned entity types now are implemented as shared types. The name of owned entity type consists of the name of the owner type + navigation property + type name. e.g. something like `{Namespace}.{OwnerType}.{Navigation}#{OwnedType}`.

So one way to adjust the above code is check the name of the entity in interest and just test directly for it. Another way closer to what are you doing before is to check the CLR type and in case it is owned, the navigation property name from owner to owned (the equivalent of the "defining navigation name"), which can be obtained with `FindOwnership().PrincipalToDependent.Name`, e.g. something like

```
if (entityEntry.Metadata.ClrType == typeof(ArticleTag)
    && entityEntry.Metadata.FindOwnership()?.PrincipalToDependent?.Name != "Tags")
```